# How to deal with issue when user doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-fullstack

When the user doesn't exist for this rather than redirecting to signup page I got this error, also I 
 tried something to change but unable to find how I can do it successfully

[image: This is my error showing after signin if that user doesn't exist]

Menu.js

```js
import React,{Fragment} from 'react';
import { Link ,withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {signout,isAuthenticated} from '../auth'
import {itemTotal} from './CartHelper'



const isActive =(history,path)=>{
    if(history.location.pathname === path){
        return {color :'#ff9900'}
    } else{
        return {color:'#ffffff'}
    }
}

/* here link component is similar to anchor tag in html */
const Menu =({history})=>{

    //const {name,email,role} = isAuthenticated()
    console.log('this is my history role ->',isAuthenticated());

    
    return(
        <div>
        <ul className="nav nav-tabs bg-primary">
            <li className="nav-list">
                <Link className="nav-link" style={isActive (history,'/')} to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-list">
                <Link className="nav-link" style={isActive (history,'/shop')} to="/shop">Shop</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-list">
                <Link className="nav-link" style={isActive (history,'/cart')} to="/cart">Cart  
                <sup>
                    <small className="cart-badge">{itemTotal()}</small>
                </sup>
                </Link>
            </li>
            

           {isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().user.role === 0 && (
               <li className="nav-list">
               <Link className="nav-link" style={isActive (history,'/user/dashboard')} to="/user/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
           </li>
           )}

            {isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().user.role === 1 && (
               <li className="nav-list">
               <Link className="nav-link" style={isActive (history,'/admin/dashboard')} to="/admin/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
           </li>
           )}



            {!isAuthenticated() && (
                <Fragment>
                    <li className="nav-list">
                <Link className="nav-link" style={isActive (history,'/signin')}to="/signin">Signin</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-list">
                <Link className="nav-link" style={isActive (history,'/signup')} to="/signup">Signup</Link>
            </li>
                </Fragment>
            )}

                {isAuthenticated() && (
                    <li className="nav-list">
                    <span className="nav-link" 
                    style={{cursor:'pointer',color:'#ffffff'}} 
                    onClick={()=>signout(()=>{
                        history.push('/');
                    })
                    }>SignOut</span>
                </li>
                )}

            
        </ul>
    </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Menu);



/* 


*/
```

Signin.js

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from '../core/Layout';
import {signin,authenticate,isAuthenticated} from '../auth'



    const Signin =()=>{

        const [values,setValues] = useState({
            email:'',
            password:'',
            error:'',
            loading:false,
            redirectToReferrer:false
        })

        // here we use redirectToReferrer because when it will be true user will be redirected to home page

// all the fields are streoed in value which is an object so we have to destructure to grab individual values

        const {email,password,loading,error,redirectToReferrer} = values

// here we are destructing user and tring to divert user to admin if role === 1 (i.e admin) fir that we are destricting


        const {user} = isAuthenticated();
       
// it is higer order function where one function return anither function 
// also here name is like a parameter in which every name,email,apssword is copied to grab current valeu to update the sate
// here we use ...values to tell about our previous state values
        const handleChange = name => event =>{
            setValues({...values,error:false,[name]:event.target.value});
            
        }




        //  now we have to send data to backend when user click on submit button so it can be done by this method
        // we used preventDefault to stop auto reload of the page after an action is performed

        const clickSubmit =(event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            setValues({...values,error:false,loading:true});
          signin({email,password}) 
     .then(data=>{
        // console.log('my data in signin',data);
           if(data.error){
                console.log('my signing error after event fired',data.error);
                setValues({...values,error:data.error,loading:false});
                
            }
            else{
                authenticate(data,()=>{
                    setValues({...values,redirectToReferrer:true})
                    
                })
            } 
        }) 
        
        // we are passing all value as an object to user parameter
           // signup({name:name,email:email,password:password})
            // when key and values name are same so we can only write values
        
        }
    const signinForm =()=>(
        <form>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Email</label> 
                <input  onChange={handleChange('email')}
                type ="email" className="form-control"
                value={email}
                />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Password</label> 
                <input   onChange={handleChange('password')}
                type ="password" className="form-control" value={password}/>
            </div>
            <button  onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );


    const showError =()=>{
        return <div className="alert alert-danger" style={{display:error?'':'none' }}>{error}</div>
     }

    const showLoading =()=>
         loading && (<div className="alert alert-info"><h2>Loading...</h2></div>);    


         // here we are redirecting user based on hos role 
         // we have done authentication already so now if the user role is 1(admin then it will be redirected to admin dashboard else to user dashboard)
         const redirectUser =()=>{
             if(redirectToReferrer){
                 if(user && user.role === 1)
                   return <Redirect to="/admin/dashboard" />
             }else{
                 return <Redirect to="/user/dashboard" />
             }
             
             }
             if(isAuthenticated()){
                return <Redirect to="/" />;
         }
        

    

    return(
        <Layout
        title="Signin"
        description="Signin to Dashboard"
        className="container col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        {showLoading()}
        {showError()}
        {signinForm()}
        {redirectUser}
     </Layout>
    )

}
       
   


export default Signin;
```

Signup.js

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Layout from '../core/Layout';
 import {signup} from '../auth'


    const Signup =(user)=>{

        const [values,setValues] = useState({
            name:'',
            email:'',
            password:'',
            error:'',
            success:false
        })

// all the fields are streoed in value which is an object so we have to destructure to grab individual values

        const {name,email,password,success,error} = values
       
// it is higer order function where one function return anither function 
// also here name is like a parameter in which every name,email,apssword is copied to grab current valeu to update the sate
// here we use ...values to tell about our previous state values
        const handleChange = name => event =>{
            setValues({...values,error:false,[name]:event.target.value});
            
        }
        //  now we have to send data to backend when user click on submit button so it can be done by this method
        // we used preventDefault to stop auto reload of the page after an action is performed
        
        const clickSubmit =(event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            setValues({...values,error:false});
            signup({name,email,password})
         //console.log("this is my data ",data);
            
    .then(data=>{
       //  console.log(data);
          if(data.error){
                setValues({...values,error:data.error,success:false});
            }
            else{
                setValues({...values,name:'',email:'',password:'',error:'',success:true})
            }
            
        }) 
        // we are passing all value as an object to user parameter
           // signup({name:name,email:email,password:password})
            // when key and values name are same so we can only write values
        
        }
    const signupForm =()=>(
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Name</label> 
                <input onChange={handleChange('name')}
                type ="text" className="form-control"
                value={name}
                
                />
        
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Email</label> 
                <input  onChange={handleChange('email')}
                type ="email" className="form-control"
                value={email}
                />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Password</label> 
                <input   onChange={handleChange('password')}
                type ="password" className="form-control" value={password}/>
            </div>
            <button  onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );

    const showError =()=>{
       return <div className="alert alert-danger" style={{display:error?'':'none' }}>{error}</div>
    }

    const showSuccess =()=>{
       return  <div className="alert alert-danger" style={{display:success?'':'none' }}>new account is created .Please <Link to="/signin">Signin</Link></div>
    }
        

    

    return(
        <Layout
        title="Signup"
        description="Signup to node React E-commerce App"
        className="container col-md-8 offset-md-2"
        
    >
        
        {showSuccess()}
        {showError()}
        {signupForm()}
        
    
     </Layout>
    )

}
       
   


export default Signup;
```

I have added all relevant file to know about the error also in which file I am getting error I have attached as well

Comment: `isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().user && isAuthenticated().user.role`

Comment: or maybe show what isAuthenticated function returns - the code is in your `auth.js`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is that before redirecting the user you are trying to access a value that is undefined which is a no go and crashes the app.

What I try to do is initialize the user values (with strings or null values) and not assign them undefined values if the response from the server is bad.

```
if(data.error){
   console.log('my signing error after event fired',data.error);
   setValues({...values,error:data.error,loading:false});           
}
```

This seems to be problematic.